# Модуль не импортируется из верхней директории

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

В проекте, который имеет следующую структуру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу импортировать в файл sql.py, лежащий в поддиректории database, файл config.py, лежащий в корневой директории.

В sql.py я прописываю `from config import PG_USER, PG_PASS, host`и получаю ошибку

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/anton/dev/Bots/EngGitBot/database/sql.py", line 5, in 
> from config import PG_USER, PG_PASS, host ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Почему в sql.py не виден конфиг?

Comment: как-то типа `from ..config import` не пробовали?

Comment: пробовал, пишет другую ошибку

Comment: И что же пишет?

Comment: @DenverToha Тут попробуйте почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107185/python-import-from-folder-above-without-using-path